# Cannot able to do intersecting properly

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below

```
var deptRecs= DepartmentRecords; //it is of type IEnumerable<Department>
var deptIDs= new string[] { "1", "2" };
var result = deptIDs.Intersect(?????)
```

I want to figure out the common department id's. What will sit in the predicate of Intersect?

Comment: So you want to take all `Department` objects that have `Id` in `deptIDs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) expects argument of the same type. Thus, to perform a set intersection, as you are trying to pass in an array of string, an example can be

```
DepartmentRecords.Select(i=>i.DepartmentName).Intersect(deptIDs);
```

I am assuming you have a `DepartmentName` property of type string. Performing a selection operation returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. Then I am passing in the array, which will return the set intersection of the two enumerables.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following instead of Intersect:

```
deptRecs.Where(d=>deptIDs.Contains(d.DeptId))
```

For intersect you need same types of entities.

Hope it helps...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Where` with `Contains` instead of `Intersect`:

```
 var result = deptRecs.Where(x => deptIDs.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Id` property of `int` type on `Department` class it is enough to filter them with `Contains()` operation

```
var result  = deptRecs.Where(r=>deptIDs.Contains(r.Id.ToString()))
```